# Property $_elements of Doctrine\ArrayCollection class change, unable to unserialize old object in database

Tags: doctrine

The property

```
private $_elements
```

of Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection was renamed to

```
private $elements
```

But i had serialized object ArrayCollection in my database. So now, my array collection is empty. (When i dump it, i can see $_elements is not empty) I want to know how to make a command to change that.

I have already try:

- replace function with mysql but i have an Notice: unserialize() error
- with ReflectionObject, but property $_elements is not defined
- runkit_method_redefine, I don't have access

Answer (score 0):

If your ArrayCollection uses only scalar elements inside then this works well:

```
//use following line only if you already have an unserialzed ArrayCollection
$data = serialize($data);

$data = unserialize($data);
$data = var_export($data, true);
$data = preg_replace('#[A-Za-z\\\]*::__set_state#', '', $data);
$data = eval('return '.$data.';');
$data = new ArrayCollection($data['_elements']);
```

If you had stored some other classes inside your ArrayCollection, they will be converted to normal arrays.

**Warning:** Please don't use this code in production, only to recover your serialized data, because eval is evil and is a high potentially security issue.